# My USB kind of shows up on Windows 10

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, chkdsk, disk-management

I have an old USB I plugged into my computer, but it doesn't show up in file explorer. I tried running `CHKDSK` on it but it said `Cannot open volume for direct access`. I tried using `FORMAT` but it also said `Cannot open volume for direct access`. When I run Disk Manager, though, the USB doesn't come up under volumes, but it appears as a Disk. I also tried changing the letter assigned to it (in Disk Manager), but it didn't do anything. How can I fix it?

PS - I know that the USB is connected because the light on it lights up. I also know that disk in Disk Manager is the USB, because it disappears when I unplug the USB.

[image: screenshot of disk manager].

Comment: The data is sufficient to confidently say it failed completely. Replace it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Okay, thanks...

Comment: @ChanganAuto But it still comes up on disk manager...

Comment: Yes, but it shows "no media". It means the actual flash memory is fried and what the the system "sees" is only the USB controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your USB Drive is broken and needs to be replaced.

A USB Drive has 2 parts. It has the ram chips that store data, and it has the controller. It seems either the controller is malfunctioning partially and it can't access the data chips, a trace between the ram chips and controller is severed or the data chip(s) is/are broken and the controller gets no volumes that way.

Either means: replace the USB drive.